# Unobtrusive JavaScript ajax with mootools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, mootools

Unobtrusive JavaScript with jQuery is available in MVC3.But how can I use the unobtrusive Javascript ajax with mootools?

Comment: What do you mean by "unobtrusive"?

Comment: @JamWaffles: He's referring to an ASP.Net MVC feature.

Comment: "Unobtrusive Javascript" is a coding and design style, not a product you install or a library you include. Does MVC3 not let you use any client-side code that you like?

Comment: @nnnnnn: i think the reference is regarding the unobstrusive validation plugin of jquery designed for mvc2+

Comment: here is the meaning of it. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html

Comment: @nnnnnn I think it's easy to achieve it(follow the jQuery version to write).But I am very weak in this area，so if there has been completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, this is trivial to do. have a look at the recently released http://mootools.net/blog/2011/12/20/mootools-behavior/, I think it supports it.

I have used this approach in my [Modal.BootStrap](http://mootools.net/forge/p/modal_bootstrap) (view source on github, link's there) as well whereby it uses data attributes to fetch data from an ajax resource, it's not quite the same but it certainly is a start.

I just spent 10 mins making this and it's a good start:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/zYLtQ/

```
(function() {

    var ajaxify = this.ajaxify = new Class({

        Implements: [Options,Events],

        options: {
            mask: "form[data-ajax=true]",
            props: {
                ajaxLoading: "data-ajax-loading",
                ajaxMode: "data-ajax-mode",
                ajaxUpdate: "data-ajax-update",
                ajaxSuccessEvent: "data-event-success"
            }  
        },

        initialize: function(options) {
            this.setOptions(options);
            this.elements = document.getElements(this.options.mask);
            this.attachEvents();
        },

        attachEvents: function() {
            this.elements.each(function(form) {
                var props = {};
                Object.each(this.options.props, function(value, key) {
                    props[key] = form.get(value) || "";
                });

                form.store("props", props);
                form.addEvent("submit", this.handleSubmit.bind(this));
            }, this);

        },

        handleSubmit: function(e) {
            e && e.stop && e.stop();
            var form = e.target, props = form.retrieve("props"), self = this;
            var updateTarget = document.getElement(props.ajaxUpdate);

            new Request({
                url: form.get("action"),
                data: form,
                onRequest: function() {
                    if (props.ajaxLoading) {
                        var loading = document.getElement(props.ajaxLoading);
                        if (loading && updateTarget) {
                            updateTarget.set("html", loading.get("html"));
                        }

                    }
                },
                onSuccess: function() {                             
                    if (!updateTarget)
                       return;

                    if(props.ajaxMode != 'append') {
                        updateTarget.set("html", this.response.text);
                    }
                    else {
                        updateTarget.adopt(new Element("div", { html: this.response.text }));
                    }     

                    if (props.ajaxSuccessEvent)
                        self.fireEvent(props.ajaxSuccessEvent, this.response);       
                }

            }).send();

        }

    });

})();


new ajaxify({
    onContactFormSuccess: function(responseObj) {
        console.log(responseObj.text);
        alert("we are done.");
    }
});
```

works with a DOM of:

```
<form action="/echo/html/" data-ajax="true"  data-ajax-loading="#loading" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#update" data-event-success="contactFormSuccess" method="post">
    <input name="delay" value="4" type="hidden" />
    <input name="html" value="Thanks for your submission, this is the jsfiddle testing response" type="hidden" />
    <input name="name" placeholder="your name" />
    <button>submit</button>
</form>

<div id="update">The update will go here.</div>  
<div id="loading">loading...</div>
```

you should be able to build on that. on refactor i'd move the request events into their own methods and add some more proofing etc but it's fine. i don't know all mvc does but one thing that is missing is form validation events. i also added a custom event that is fired when done so your ajaxifier instance can do something particular to that form (see `data-event-success="contactFormSuccess"`)

also, it can use default request options if not implicitly specified, even what request object to create - Request, Request.HTML, Request.JSON etc. Events like onRequest, spinners etc are also feasible... I think you just need to work your way through the options that mvc provides and build them to get started.

```
Confirm     data-ajax-confirm
HttpMethod  data-ajax-method
InsertionMode   data-ajax-mode *
LoadingElementDuration  data-ajax-loading-duration **
LoadingElementId    data-ajax-loading
OnBegin     data-ajax-begin
OnComplete  data-ajax-complete
OnFailure   data-ajax-failure
OnSuccess   data-ajax-success
UpdateTargetId  data-ajax-update
Url     data-ajax-url
```